# Redirect a url if it doesn't have a string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Please see the following three url

```
1)www.example.com/product/anystring/
2)www.example.com/product/selected/
3)www.example.com/product-all/
```

Here the allowed url for the product is  **www.example.com/product/selected/** with a element  **id**  . So the allowed url for the product is like **www.example.com/product/selected/?id=1**,
**www.example.com/product/selected/?id=2**  , **www.example.com/product/selected/?id=3** etc

so please see the first url www.example.com/product/**string**/ .

So here after product there is /string is coming . So it is not allowed .

so if some one enter to www.example.com/product/anystring/ i need to redirect to www.example.com/product-all/ . How i can do this ?

Example

```
1) www.example.com/product/selected/?id=3 (no redirection needed )
2) www.example.com/product/selected/?id=14 (no redirection needed )
3) www.example.com/product/selected/?id=24 (no redirection needed )

4) www.example.com/product/test/  need  redirection to  www.example.com/product-all/
5) www.example.com/product/pen/  need  redirection to  www.example.com/product-all/
6) www.example.com/product/apple/  need  redirection to  www.example.com/product-all/
```

Comment: You can add those rules to your `.htaccess` file. Ex: `RewriteRule  ^/product/test/ /product-all/  [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: But the thing is it's not only the test , any string that not contain /selected/?id=*

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule as **top rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^product/[\w-]+)/?$ /product-all/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# other rules go here
```

Comment: so for this www.example.com/product/selected/?id=3 (no redirection needed ) . it will be ok ?

Comment: Did you verify on your website?